# Plone restart after buildout fails. How to find the error

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

lately I have been trying to customize my Plone by adding helpful addons via the eggs section of my buildout.cfg, running `buildout` and restarting the zeocluster `plonectl restart`.
I have succesfully installed several addons this way.
But some stop Plone from working. For example trying to add `plone.app.ldap`:
buildout works fine and also the restart of the server works initially, but when accessing Plone in the browser it doesn't load and `plonectl status` tells me my two clients have lost connection to the zeoserver. The events log tells the same story, but other than that I do not see which error caused the problem. When i remove the addon everything works fine again.

Is the way I am handling my addons correct? Did I miss something? Where can I find additional information what crashes my zeocluster?

Comment: pls update your question with some debug data, so it would made much more sense to others...

Comment: @Mathias The entire premise of the question is that there *is* no "debug data" and the asker wants some; complaining that the asker didn't include an error message in a question about how to see an error message doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Comment: I was not able to help, thats why I asked for some more infos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some problems are swallowed on startup.  You can see them by starting your client on the foreground with `bin/zeoclient fg`.
See http://docs.plone.org/manage/troubleshooting/basic.html
Note: the zeoclient script may be called client, or client1 or instance or something like that, depending on how it is named in the buildout.

This will probably show a Python traceback.  Maybe the add-on is missing a dependency.  That would be a problem to report to the add-on authors.  Adding the missing dependency to the eggs add rerunning buildout should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem. Here is how I fixed it:

Mention clearly the version you wish to install for the Add-on in the [versions] section of buildout.cfg.

> [versions]
>
> ...
>
> 'add-on' = 'version'

Open the documentation of the add-on, probably on pypi resources, check for the versions. It so happens that plone automatically gets the version for you while running buildout and the add-ons, not compatible with your version of plone are installed. So it is always better to specify your version requirements.